# Como disminuyo valor digito mediante un boton (resta) y que se vuelva a restar intermitentemente en Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, botón, activity

Hola a todos SOY NUEVO en esto de la programacion y ando tratando de hacer una resta y que el resultado de esa resta se vuelva a restar con otro numero que yo ponga en un edit-text (digito) hasta llegar a 0. ¿Como puedo repetir que se haga la misma resta?

por ejemplo: tv1 es un editext tiene el digito 50 y ocrResultview es un editext pongo el digito 30 cuando doy click al boton de btn_resta hago que el ocrtResultview y el tv1 me haga la resta queda perfecto ahi. pero cuando vuelvo a presionar el boton restar asignando otro numero por ejemplo 10 el numero que digite nuevamente me marca el digito del primer tv1 del principio que fue el 50 no hago que el nuevo digito que puse reste de nuevo a que el resultado sea 10. ejemplo (50-30=20) y de apartir del 20 (20-10=10) quiero que cuando ponga un digito nuevo me respete el que tiene y que pueda restarse nuevamente reduciendo la cantidad, espero poderme explicar.

Resta.java

```
    TextView ocrResultView, tv1;
Button btn_resta2;
{
}
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

    String n1 = ocrResultView.getText().toString();
    String n2 = tv1.getText().toString();

    int entero1 =Integer.parseInt(n1);
    int entero2 =Integer.parseInt(n2);

    int rta=0;

    switch (view.getId()){
        case R.id.btn_resta:
            rta=entero1-entero2;

            break;
    }
    tv1.setText(""+rta);

}
```

Comment: Hola, evita realizar la misma pregunta varias veces, agrega detalles que ayuden a la comunidad saber cuál es el problema, te aseguro obtendrás de esta forma la ayuda deseada, revisar [ask]. Es la tercera vez que agregas la misma pregunta https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/580356/como-disminuyo-valor-digito-mediante-un-boton-resta-intermitentemente-en-andro y https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/578446/como-disminuyo-digito-mediante-un-boton-restar-intermitentemente-en-android-st

Comment: @Menchaca Moto, quedo muy bien explicado ahora, pero toma en cuenta lo que te dice Jorgesys, cuando tienes algo que corregir o agregar, usa el botón **editar** que está debajo de tu pregunta y modifica lo que desees, de esa manera te ahorraras recibir votos negativos.

Comment: Entendido, @Jorgesys, Marce puente. volvere a dejar siempre la misma pregunta, espero que me puedan ayudar se los agradeceria.

Comment: @MenchacaMoto gracias, es importante agregar detalles para que la comunidad te ayude de mejor forma, agreguè respuesta, saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que deseas es que `tv1` obtenga el resultado de la resta y continúe restando.

El resultado de la resta debe ser un valor absoluto, pero cuando la resta sea menor que 0, será 0 el resultado total.

```
   @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        String n1 = ocrResultView.getText().toString();
        String n2 = tv1.getText().toString();

        int entero1 =Integer.parseInt(n1);
        int entero2 =Integer.parseInt(n2);

        int rta=0;

        switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.btn_resta:
                rta=entero1-entero2;
                rta = Math.abs(rta); // obtiene valor absoluto
                break;
        }
        tv1.setText(""+rta);
    }
```

Pero para no estar desplegando valores negativos,lo mejor es que cuando `ocrResultView` tenga un valor mayor o igual que `tv1`, definas el resultado predeterminado como 0.

```
   @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        String n1 = ocrResultView.getText().toString();
        String n2 = tv1.getText().toString();

        int entero1 =Integer.parseInt(n1);
        int entero2 =Integer.parseInt(n2);

        int rta=0;

        switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.btn_resta:
                if(entero1 >= entero2 ){
                    rta = 0; //Si entero1 (ocrResultView) es mayor, siempre darìa 0.
                }else {
                    rta = entero1 - entero2;
                    rta = Math.abs(rta); // obtiene valor absoluto
                }
                break;
        }
        tv1.setText(""+rta);
    }
```

Comment: Bendecido seas! me funciono correctamente!! saludos!" :